# Laravel Echo not subscribing to private Channel

Tags: laravel, websocket, pusher, laravel-echo

- Echo Version: 1.8.0
- Laravel Version: 7.0
- PHP Version: 7.2.
- NPM Version: 6.12.1
- Node Version: 12.13.1

#### Description: I'm trying to send notifications to users,

My pusher connection is good because it sends on public channels
And also, i get this message on my console
`[2020-07-24 21:08:09][355] Processed:  Illuminate\Notifications\Events\BroadcastNotificationCreated`
and on pusher i also see that the message was sent.
I also don't get any errors on my browser console as all the websocket connections are working well.
But i still dont get any messages.
I tried

```
Echo.private('App.User.' +userId)
   .notification((notification) => {
   console.log(notification);
  });
```

I also tried

```
Echo.private('App.User.' + userId)
  .listen('.Illuminate\\Notifications\\Events\\BroadcastNotificationCreated', (e) => {
  console.log('Event Notification received ', e)
  });
```

Now I turned on Pusher error logging and i got
`app.js:42600 Pusher :  : ["JSON returned from auth endpoint was invalid, yet status code was 200. Data was: <!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html lang=\"en\">\r\n`

I also followed many tutorials and the docs
All to no avail.

#### Steps To Reproduce:

Create a notification and declare both the toArray method and toBroadcast methods but echo fails to catch messages from pusher

Comment: You need to setup the authorization routes - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting#authorizing-channels

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this issue myself

**Steps**

In my bootstrap.js file

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
      broadcaster: "pusher",
      key: "my key",
      cluster: "eu",
      encrypted: true,
      authEndpoint: "api/broadcasting/auth",
      auth: {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      },
    });
```

Then in my routes/api.php file,

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('broadcasting/auth', function (Request $request) {
    $pusher = new Pusher\Pusher(
    $app_key,
    $app_secret,
    $app_id
);
return $pusher->socket_auth($request->request->get('private-my-channel'),($request->request->get('socket_id'));
});
```

There is more info on this in the [documentation](https://packagist.org/packages/pusher/pusher-php-server),
I hope it helps someone someday